# Dependency problem with vue-cli-service serve

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

When I try to build my VueJS typescript app I get the following dependency errors.

> vue-cli-service serve

INFO  Starting development server...
Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
 98% after emitting CopyPlugin

ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                                                                                                                        9:05:52 PM
These dependencies were not found:

- core-js/modules/es6.function.name in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Resources.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
- core-js/modules/es6.string.includes in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Resources.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
- core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint8-array in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Resources.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
- core-js/modules/es7.array.includes in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Resources.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
- core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Resources.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&

To install them, you can run: npm install --save core-js/modules/es6.function.name core-js/modules/es6.string.includes core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint8-array core-js/modules/es7.array.includes core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable
No type errors found
No lint errors found
Version: typescript 3.5.2, tslint 5.17.0

Then when I run the suggested npm command at the end of the error list I get the following error.

npm install --save core-js/modules/es6.function.name core-js/modules/es6.string.includes core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint8-array core-js/modules/es7.array.includes core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "core-js\modules\es6.function.name" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Comment: have you installed core-js? `yarn add core-js` - this is mostly used in polyfills and such

Answer (score 2):

`npm add core-js` did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I've read several places that installing `core-js` will solve the problem, but installing that just by name will get you `core-js@3` at the moment, and v3 is still only half baked and/or incompatible with the way that it's being used by the Vue CLI/Babel/Webpack tools. Specifically installing `core-js@2` seems to fix the issue we're having. This is what got it the `vue serve` command working for me again on new, as well as existing projects:

```sh
npm install --save-dev @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global core-js@2
```

Good luck!