# ganache installed in vue app, but not detected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web3js, ganache

I started a fresh vue project (vue2) and installed both ganache and web3.  I get the following error when I try starting my app:

```
* ganache in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

Here's what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "unrival_client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache": "^6.4.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0",
    "web3": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service-global": "^4.5.15",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Edit: Here's what my vue component looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    hi
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const Web3 = require("web3");
const ganache = require("ganache");
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider(), null, { transactionConfirmationBlocks: 1 });


export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    created () {
        console.log(web3)
    }
}
</script>
```

Edit: I also get this error using es6 style importing:

```
import Web3 from "web3";
import ganache from "ganache";
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider(), null, { transactionConfirmationBlocks: 1 });
```

I've tried re-running the command suggested in the error message but it doesn't help.  Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Add your HelloWorld component snippet code to your question which error noted.

Comment: @MohammadHosseinDolatabadi. okay, added it

Comment: If looks like the same error as questioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844131/dependency-problem-with-vue-cli-service-serve

Comment: @Luuk. I don't think that's the problem; I tried both suggestions in that thread but I get the same error.  Also updated my question with new `package.json`

Comment: Did you try ES6 module import instead of commonjs?

Comment: @MohammadHosseinDolatabadi   I just tried using `import` ... `from` and I get the same error :(

Comment: You cannot use `ganache` client side in this way, you must use the UMD bundle they provide.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy. I don't know what that means, could you point me to an example?

Comment: Yes, in the documentation they state that client-side (browser) usage should reference their UMD bundle, [have a look here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache#browser-use)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it looks like the link they provide `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ganache@{VERSION}/dist/web/ganache.min.js` is invalid when version is replaced with the latest `6.4.5`.  I also can't find any working previous versions